# how to use Static files that are stored in a CDN (or any external) location?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cdn

I'm trying to create an example app, using asp.net core 6 and Angular, I have everything in place and working fine when I try to specify the "DIST" folder like this (when files are all together)

```
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "angularFolder/dist";
    });
```

But, what if I would like to have the Dist folder in another server, like a CDN or for my local example, I would create a separated IIS app and store it there. I did some research here, but found nothing useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0

How can I tell to my service setup, that the files should be taken from an external source? Is this even possible?

Comment: What you can do, is to host your files on the CDN like intended. Then when you try to reach your server from that location, you will get CORS errors. You need to let your server know that it will receive requests from the CDN origin and it should respond to them. Check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) out.

Comment: But I'm not able to get the files from a CDN, the problem i'm explaining here is that the rootPath seems to require a physical local folder, not a web url. I know I will have the CORS error as soon I pass this issue, so that would help later.

Comment: You use that path _only_ when you want to serve your frontend files (index.html, javascript, css, etc) using _your backend server_. When you don't want to do this (aka using a CDN), then you don't need this at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider making use of the .net reverse proxy.

In this case, you can get your Host to "fetch" files from a separate CDN (where your static files reside)

The reverse proxy is then able to understand "how" to route your request to the correct "external" source..

```
"Clusters": {
      "cluster1": {
        "Destinations": {
          "frontend/destination1": {
            "Address": "https://yourcdn.com/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

What's great about this - is that you can then easily separate your .Net application from your Angular front end static application.

More info can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy